# Can not receive CAN DATA from Arduino UNO with MCP2515 Module

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to receive CAN DATA from Arduino UNO with MCP2515 Module.
I'm not using CAN-BUS Shield(http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/CAN-BUS_Shield) and am only using MCP2515 Module(MCP2515 CAN Controller with TJA1050 CAN transceiver.)
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/MCP2515-CAN-Bus-Module-Board-TJA1050-Receiver-SPI-For-51-MCU-ARM-Controller-NEW/32581650373.html?spm=2114.01010208.8.8.aabjPj

I think that even though I do not use CAN-BUS Shield, I should be able to receive CAN DATA through the MCP2515 module because it includes MCP2515 CAN controller and TJA1050 CAN transceiver.. **Is it right?**

I downloaded MCP_CAN_LIB source files. (https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib)

I opened a "receive" example of MCP_CAN_LIB from Arduino IDE and initialized like "CAN0.begin(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHz)" because my chinese clone MCP2515 moudule has 8 Mhz crystal.

But I could not receive any CAN DATA.
The function "digitalRead(2)" always returns HIGH..

Has anyone got this problem?

Comment: I just started working with Arduino CAN and have come to the exact same question as above using 8MHz MCP2515 modules.  I've tried multiple libraries, and finally settled on the latest one by CoryJFowler at (https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib).  Anyone have a clear answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/Flori1989/MCP2515_lib) library?It supports 8MHZ MCP2515 modules as well.

Comment: Hi Aminiok, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I also tried to use the library that you recommended, but I couldn't receive any CAN dada. It worked well if I send a RPM message(02 01 0C 00 00 00 00 00) on ID 0x7DF and then receive directly, but if I only execute a receive example, I couldn't receive any data. My vehicle is Tiguan 2015 and I'm using CAN line(High(6 pin)/Low(14 pin)) of OBDII connector. Is my vehicle different with other vehicle? Or Should I have to do something? I'm wondering whether I must send any massages before receiving or not. Thanks